# Inverse Laplace transform, none factorable denominator

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives, laplace-transform, completing-the-square

I am really stumpted on this problem and can't seem to figure out where to go from where I am. Can anyone give me some advice or hint where I should do next? Here is the problem:
$$L^{-1}(\frac{8s+8}{(s^2 + 2s + 5)^2})$$
So what I did was this:
$$L^{-1}(\frac{8s+8}{(s^2 + 2s + 5)^2})=L^{-1}(-4(-\frac{d}{ds})(\frac{1}{s^2+2s+5}))$$
Then by completing the square and simplying the negatives I got this:
$$=L^{-1}(4\frac{d}{ds}(\frac{1}{(s+1)^2 + 4}))$$
Simplying again I get:
$$=4tL^{-1}(\frac{1}{(s+1)^2 + 4})$$
And this is where I get stuck.

One: I am not sure if what I have done up until not is correct.

Two: I am not sure what inverse Laplace transform this would be or how to get it.

I think that I have to use the first shifting theorem in order to solve this inverse Laplace transform. This is what I think it should look like or something similar:
$$=4te^{-t}L^{-1}(\frac{1}{s^2+4})$$
But this gives:
$$=2te^{-t}sin(2t)$$
Which I know is not the answer. So can anyone give me some help or point me in the right direction, it would be greatly apprecaited.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2 t e^{-t} \sin(2t)$ is correct.
Why do you think that's not the answer?  If you have been given a different answer, it may have been expressed in a different form (e.g. expanding $\sin(2t)$ as $2 \sin(t)\cos(t)$).

Comment: I was given this answer: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+laplace+transform+of+%288s%2B8%29%2F%28s%5E2%2B2s%2B5%29%5E2 Under alternate forms the first one

Comment: oh sorry stupid mistake now I see that yes this is the right answer because the 2's multiply to make 4. Thanks!